# Break Out Years and Assign Values Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that is summarized based on the number of items that are bought across a span of time.  My data looks like the following:

> Customer Number     Number Of Products Sold          Start Date       End Date
>
> 1523                          6                       2006              2008

So what I would like to do is break out the data so as to assign the number of products sold across the span of time that the person was a customer.  Basically I am trying to reverse summarize the data to get the individual data points (I know that it will not be exactly accurate as to when they actually purchased the products).  So in the above example, customer 1523 was a customer in 2006, 2007, and 2008.  I would like to create a macro in visual basic in excel that strips this data out and reformats it as the following:

> Customer Number    Number of products Sold    Year
>
> 1523                      2                 2006
>
> 1523                      2                 2007
>
> 1523                      2                 2008

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from doing this?  Specifically what's the problem?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have over 500 lines of data so it would be very time consuming to break each line out individually.  Basically I am trying to generate details from summary data.

Comment: I understand that.  But are you saying you don't know any VBA so you'd like someone to write some code for you?

Comment: I know some basic VBA, but I'm not sure how to go about coding it because it is rather complicated.

Comment: You can loop over the rows in your original data, and within your loop use a second `For [startyear] To [endyear]` loop to add the rows to a new table. Divide the "number of products sold" by (endyear-startyear)+1

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rw As Range, yrStart As Long, yrEnd As Long
    Dim num, numYr, yr, cust
    Dim rngDest As Range

    Set rngDest = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2")

    For Each rw In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D11").Rows
        cust = rw.Cells(1).Value
        num = rw.Cells(2).Value
        yrStart = rw.Cells(3).Value
        yrEnd = rw.Cells(4).Value
        numYr = num / ((yrEnd - yrStart) + 1)

        For yr = yrStart To yrEnd
            rngDest.Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(cust, numYr, yr)
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
        Next yr

    Next rw

End Sub
```